# Active record "date" and "nationality" function giving me error. (Undefined method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

I am trying to create a profile page where I can input "born_on". It will be using the

```
class CreateWineMakers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :wine_makers do |t|
      t.string :name 
      t.date :born_on
      t.text :nationality
      t.text :profile 
      t.text :wine 
      t.integer :wine_list_id
      t.timestamps
    end

     add_index :wine_makers, :wine_list_id
    end
 end
```

Here is my view file.

```
<%= simple_form_for WineMaker.new do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :name %>
     <%= f.input :profile %>
     <%= f.input :wine %>
     <%= f.input :born_on %>
     <br/>
     <%= f.submit "Create", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

The "born_on" is giving me error saying the method is not defined. I am confused since all other inputs are working except "born_on" and "nationality". Before, my "born_on" was named "birth_date", and I thought the naming convention was wrong and changed it to "born_on". Here is the controller.

```
class WineMakersController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @wine_maker = WineMaker.new
    end

    def create
      @wine_maker = WineMaker.create(wine_maker_params)
      redirect_to wine_list_path(@wine_list)
    end


    def show
    end

    private

    def wine_maker_params
    params.require(:wine_maker).permit(:name, :born_on, :nationality,   :profile, :wine )
    end
end
```

This seems like such an easy question that I couldn't find similar problems..

Thank you.

Comment: Have you changed the existing migration? If so and if this is the latest migration run `rake db:migrate:redo`

Comment: @BroiSatse Thank you so much! Every time I updated my active record, I've been just doing "rake db:migrate" on top of existing ones. This worked. Thank you so much!